# Magento 1.9 API Cannot get Grouped products

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When querying products - I cannot get any grouped ones - either individually or a list of products.  the simple ones come through fine.. but not grouped.  Ideas?

(Magento 1.9.2)

```
"Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to     Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest_Admin_V1::_filterOutArrayKeys() must be an     array, null given, called in /home/www/r2h/www.return2health.net-new/public/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Rest/Admin/V1.php on line 50 and defined  in /home/www/r2h/www.return2health.net-new/public/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Rest/Admin/V1.php on line 71",
    "trace": "#0 

etc..
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Sure - I have moved to Magento stack exchange. Cheers.